# Class name dynamically in hasOne not working

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

```
public function getResource() {
 return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'resource_id']);
}
```

this function working fine but when i use this

```
public function getResource() {
 $model = ucfirst($this->resource_type);
 return $this->hasOne($model::className(), ['id' => 'resource_id']);
}
```

its give me error "Class 'User' not found".
Thanks

Comment: use app\models\User : add this line at top

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to use the name including namespace if you specify it dynamically.

```
 public function getResource() {
    $model = "api\\models\\".ucfirst($this->resource_type);
    return $this->hasOne($model::className(), ['id' => 'resource_id']);
}
```